# Finding out what changed via postUpdate listener in Symfony 2.1

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a postUpdate listener and I'd like to know what the values were prior to the update and what the values for the DB entry were after the update. Is there a way to do this in Symfony 2.1? I've looked at what's stored in getUnitOfWork() but it's empty since the update has already taken place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#preupdate). What I needed was actually part of preUpdate(). I needed to call getEntityChangeSet() on the LifecycleEventArgs.

My code:

```
public function preUpdate(Event\LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
{   
    $changeArray = $eventArgs->getEntityChangeSet();

    //do stuff with the change array

}
```

Comment: Did you mean `preUpdate(Event\PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs)` ? The method `getEntityChangeSet()` does not exist in `LifecycleEventArgs`

Comment: link Permission Denied

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events here the lifecycle-events

Answer (score 9):

You can use this ansfer [Symfony2 - Doctrine - no changeset in post update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554634/symfony2-doctrine-no-changeset-in-post-update#comment58799694_35555194)

```
/**
 * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
 */
public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $changeArray = $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($args->getObject());
}
```

Comment: Function `getEntityManager` has been deprecated. Use `getObjectManager` instead

Answer (score 1):

Your Entitiy:

```
/**
 * Order
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="order")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\EntityListeners(
 *     {"\EventListeners\OrderListener"}
 * )
 */
class Order
{
...
```

Your listener:

```
class OrderListener
{
    protected $needsFlush = false;
    protected $fields = false;

    public function preUpdate($entity, LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        if (!$this->isCorrectObject($entity)) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->setFields($entity, $eventArgs);
    }


    public function postUpdate($entity, LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        if (!$this->isCorrectObject($entity)) {
            return null;
        }

        foreach ($this->fields as $field => $detail) {
            echo $field. ' was  ' . $detail[0]
                       . ' and is now ' . $detail[1];

            //this is where you would save something
        }

        $eventArgs->getEntityManager()->flush();

        return true;
    }

    public function setFields($entity, LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $this->fields = array_diff_key(
            $eventArgs->getEntityChangeSet(),
            [ 'modified'=>0 ]
        );

        return true;
    }

    public function isCorrectObject($entity)
    {
        return $entity instanceof Order;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find [example](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate) in doctrine documentation.

```
class NeverAliceOnlyBobListener
{
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        if ($eventArgs->getEntity() instanceof User) {
            if ($eventArgs->hasChangedField('name') && $eventArgs->getNewValue('name') == 'Alice') {
                $eventArgs->setNewValue('name', 'Bob');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP specifically asked for "values were prior to the update and what the values for the DB entry were after the update", your response requires a method call for each column that would need to be hardcoded.