# Symfony2 - Doctrine - no changeset in post update

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

So i am sending an email when a certain value on an entity is changed. I only want the email to send after the update in case the update fails for what ever reason. so on the preUpdate I can do this

```
public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args){

    if ($args->hasChangedField('value') && is_null($args->getOldValue('value'))) {
        $this->sendEmail();
    }

}
```

but i need to do this on postUpdate and as these methods are not available on postUpdate i refactored it to look like this:

```
public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args){

    $entity      = $args->getEntity();
    $changeSet = $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($entity);

    if ($entity  instanceof Entity && isset( $changeSet['value'] ) && empty( $changeSet['value'][0] )) {
        $this->sendEmail();
    }
}
```

However this returns an empty change set, but changes have been made and can be seen in preUpdate. Can anyone see what i am doing wrong? help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I think that on PostUpdate event Doctrine in not following already any changes - and changeset will be empty. You need to get changeset in preupdate and deal with it from this place.

Comment: Ok thanks, Im sure i have got the changeset in postUpdate before which is whats confused me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On `preUpdate` event you get event object of class `PreUpdateEventArgs` where You have change set for entity.

On `postUpdate` you just get event object of class `LifecycleEventArgs` where you can ask only for Updated entity (and get latest state of it).

If you want to play with changeset then you need to do it before actual updating entity (`preUpdate` event).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I managed to find a previous symfony2 project i worked on and i am able to access the changeset in the post update using the following line `$changeSet = $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($entity);`. But the exact same line in th eproject im on at the moment doesn't work. I guess it must be a different issue somewhere

Comment: Thank you ! Changing `postUpdate` to `preUpdate` did the trick for me (I copy pasted from another config but forget to change)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround could be to save change set somewhere by yourself and later retrieve it in `postUpdate`. It is a siplified exaple I've implement once:

```
<?php

namespace Awesome\AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

/**
 * Store last entity change set in memory, so that it could be
 * usable in postUpdate event.
 */
class EntityChangeSetStorageListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCache
     */
    private $cache;

    /**
     * @param ArrayCache $cacheStorage
     */
    public function __construct(ArrayCache $cacheStorage)
    {
        $this->cache = $cacheStorage;
    }

    /**
     * Store last entity change set in memory.
     *
     * @param PreUpdateEventArgs $event
     */
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getEntity();

        $this->cache->setNamespace(get_class($entity));
        $this->cache->save($entity->getId(), $event->getEntityChangeSet());
    }

    /**
     * Release the memory.
     */
    public function onClear()
    {
        $this->clearCache();
    }

    /**
     * Clear cache.
     */
    private function clearCache()
    {
        $this->cache->flushAll();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Events::preUpdate,
            Events::onClear,
        ];
    }
}
```

Later inject ChangeSetStorage service to the listener where it is necessary on `postUpdate` event.

Answer (score -1):

I had a really annoying issue with the changeset data, sometimes I got the collection of changes and sometimes not.

I sorted out by adding this line **$event->getEntityManager()->refresh($entity);** in the **prePersist** and **preUpdate** events inside a **doctrine.event_subscriber**

After the refresh line, changesetdata was updated so the following line started to work:

```
/** @var array $changeSet */
$changeSet = $this->em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
```

Comment: All the answers are outdated for symfony 6, and only this answer was on the right track `$eventArgs->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($eventArgs->getObject());`